# Sorting a float number against a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I think I finally found the source of an irritating problem.  I am sorting an array of objects by the price of a product and sometimes the product price is not available denoted an "N/A".  I am expecting all the values of "N/A" to be put last in the total sort order...but its not turning out that way.  It seems to work for a bit, all prices listed first and then prices and N/A's are interspersed towards the bottom of the sort.  How/What can I do to solve this issue?

```
var arr = [
  {id:0,vendor:'ACompany',price:'10.82'},
  {id:1,vendor:'ZCompany',price:'10.00'},
  {id:2,vendor:'LCompany',price:'9.82'},
  {id:3,vendor:'DCompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:4,vendor:'WCompany',price:'11.82'},
  {id:5,vendor:'RCompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:6,vendor:'HCompany',price:'10.83'},
  {id:7,vendor:'MCompany',price:'10.72'},
  {id:8,vendor:'XCompany',price:'9.92'},
  {id:9,vendor:'ICompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:10,vendor:'GCompany',price:'10.82'},
] ;

function sortArr(key) {
    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var x = a[key]; var y = b[key] ;
    if (key == "vendor") {
      return ((x<y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1: 0)) ;
    } else {
      return parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y) ;
    }
  })
}

sortArr('price') ;  // when sorting by 'vendor', it works fine.
for (x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
    console.log(arr[x].vendor+ ": " +arr[x].price) ;
}
```

The Sort output is:

```
LCompany: 9.82
XCompany: 9.92
ZCompany: 10.00
MCompany: 10.72
ACompany: 10.82
GCompany: 10.82
DCompany: N/A
ICompany: N/A
HCompany: 10.83
WCompany: 11.82
RCompany: N/A
```

And I know I can't try to parse the prices as strings, the 'N/A's will be last, but $10 values will be listed before $9 values.

Comment: @user202729 It's in the question.  Please read questions before commenting :)

Comment: *`If both values are 'N/A', return 0, if one of them is 'N/A', that's lower, else compare price.`*

Comment: @Archer I mean, the "fix the bug" is somewhat independent of the "write the sort function"...

Comment: @Archer So it feels like "I've completed problem A, it worked, but now I faced problem B, I don't know how to do it and I didn't try anything, anyone help?"

Comment: @user202729 If you think this question shows no effort then you're being unfairly critical.  You don't have to help if you don't want to.

Comment: Wow....what turned out to be a very simple solution that if I had had my 3rd cup of coffee I may have eventually figured out.  But beyond that, my post lit up a firestorm of comments, solutions, and the ire of more than a few individuals.  Thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is close, but needs to handle non-numeric input as a special exception.  You can detect if the string is non-numeric as follows: `isNaN(parseFloat("N/A")) == true`, `isNaN(parseFloat("3.0")) == false`.

The problem is because NaN has **no** ordering. NaN < NaN == false, NaN > NaN == false, and NaN == NaN == false.

So before you decide to sort numerically with `parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y)` in your code, check for that condition and use a different ordering of your choosing.

```js
var arr = [
    {id:0,vendor:'ACompany',price:'10.82'},
    {id:1,vendor:'ZCompany',price:'10.00'},
    {id:2,vendor:'LCompany',price:'9.82'},
    {id:3,vendor:'DCompany',price:'N/A'},
    {id:4,vendor:'WCompany',price:'11.82'},
    {id:5,vendor:'RCompany',price:'N/A'},
    {id:6,vendor:'HCompany',price:'10.83'},
    {id:7,vendor:'MCompany',price:'10.72'},
    {id:8,vendor:'XCompany',price:'9.92'},
    {id:9,vendor:'ICompany',price:'N/A'},
    {id:10,vendor:'GCompany',price:'10.82'},
] ;

function sortArr(key) {
    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var x = a[key]; var y = b[key] ;
    if (key == "vendor") {
      return ((x<y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1: 0)) ;
    } else {
      return isNaN(+x) ? 1 : isNaN(+y) ? -1 : parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y) ;
    }
})
}

sortArr('price') ;  // when sorting by 'vendor', it works fine.
for (x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
    console.log(arr[x].vendor+ ": " +arr[x].price) ;
}
```

This solution is slightly more robust than just handling 'N/A', since it will also put any non-numeric input at the bottom, though not in a specified order.

Comment: @JeremyThille There, that should do it.

Comment: The snippet works, but not the code :/ N/A are at the top, they should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You can first sort it by not `NaN` values and then by price values.

```js
var arr = [{id:0,vendor:'ACompany',price:'10.82'},{id:1,vendor:'ZCompany',price:'10.00'},{id:2,vendor:'LCompany',price:'9.82'},{id:3,vendor:'DCompany',price:'N/A'},{id:4,vendor:'WCompany',price:'11.82'},{id:5,vendor:'RCompany',price:'N/A'},{id:6,vendor:'HCompany',price:'10.83'},{id:7,vendor:'MCompany',price:'10.72'},{id:8,vendor:'XCompany',price:'9.92'},{id:9,vendor:'ICompany',price:'N/A'},{id:10,vendor:'GCompany',price:'10.82'}];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let aN = +a.price, bN = +b.price;
  return !isNaN(bN) - !isNaN(aN) || aN - bN
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Subtracting booleans?? `false-false==0`, `false-true==-1`, `true-false==1`, mind blown. Javascript is WEIRD

Comment: @Jeremy Not necessarily in a pleasant way…  But yes, it works.

Comment: @JeremyThille I guess most languages just do that. C, C++, Python.

Comment: Really? I never knew

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom sorter instead.

In short, numeric prices will be sorted at the top of the array and all N/A price types will be sorted down to the bottom.  I'd recommend reading about custom sorters here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
var arr = [
  {id:0,vendor:'ACompany',price:'10.82'},
  {id:1,vendor:'ZCompany',price:'10.00'},
  {id:2,vendor:'LCompany',price:'9.82'},
  {id:3,vendor:'DCompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:4,vendor:'WCompany',price:'11.82'},
  {id:5,vendor:'RCompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:6,vendor:'HCompany',price:'10.83'},
  {id:7,vendor:'MCompany',price:'10.72'},
  {id:8,vendor:'XCompany',price:'9.92'},
  {id:9,vendor:'ICompany',price:'N/A'},
  {id:10,vendor:'GCompany',price:'10.82'}
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.price == b.price) return 0;
  if (a.price == "N/A") return 1;
  if (b.price == "N/A") return -1;
  return a.price - b.price;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the property has a string and get the delta of the comparison fo a chained retuen value.

```js
var array = [{ id: 0, vendor: 'ACompany', price: '10.82' }, { id: 1, vendor: 'ZCompany', price: '10.00' }, { id: 2, vendor: 'LCompany', price: '9.82' }, { id: 3, vendor: 'DCompany', price: 'N/A' }, { id: 4, vendor: 'WCompany', price: '11.82' }, { id: 5, vendor: 'RCompany', price: 'N/A' }, { id: 6, vendor: 'HCompany', price: '10.83' }, { id: 7, vendor: 'MCompany', price: '10.72' }, { id: 8, vendor: 'XCompany', price: '9.92' }, { id: 9, vendor: 'ICompany', price: 'N/A' }, { id: 10, vendor: 'GCompany', price: '10.82' }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.price === 'N/A') - (b.price === 'N/A') || a.price - b.price;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need that N/A's in your output? Filter them out `_.filter(arr, ({price}) => price !== 'N/A')` and then pass the result to a sort function. A sort function shouldn't know about N/A I guess, it should just do the sorting.

Comment: So what's your actual solution?

Answer (score -3):

You should check `isNaN(parseFloat(x))` and `isNaN(parseFloat(y))` before returning the result : if one is `NaN` then put it last